# Java DateTimeFormat pattern?

Tags: java, date

I need help with my date format, I can't see what I am missing.

Format : `EEEE d'th' 'of' MMMM yyyy hh:mm:ss a`
Date : `Wednesday 6th of April 2016 06:10:08 AM`
Tryied [here](http://www.sdfonlinetester.info/) and seems to work.

Does someone have any idea ?

Additional infos
- Tested with `SimpleDateFormat`
- Tested with `Joda time (DateTimeFormat)` v2.1

**EDIT :**
Both solutions Ihave tried are not working.
Here is the stack trace

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Wednesday 6th of April 2016 06:1..."
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:866)
    at com.thales.communications.webintlab.ewr.spider.impl.PasteBinSpiderTest.lolTest(PasteBinSpiderTest.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

***EDIT 2 :***
Unit test throwing the error   :

```
@Test
    public void formatTest() throws ParseException {
        final DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEEE d'th of' MMMM yyyy hh:mm:ss a");

        dtf.parseDateTime("Wednesday 6th of April 2016 06:10:08 AM");
    }
```

Thanks for you help

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: I can't wait for the 1th of May!

Comment: The `...` in your `String` means it doesn't follow your format; it stops after `1`.

Comment: How are you trying to parse that string?? I need to see the souce code!

Comment: Done :). Thank you for this precision Eliott Frisch

Comment: Also don't forget to use the correct `Locale`, since you're working with words and they are locale dependent.

Comment: @Tom Adding the locale did the trick. Forgot how parsing date was a pleasure :D.
Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The day/month/AM/PM marker fields may not match those of your default Locale (Looks like [French](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2429178/ogdabou))

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = 
        DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEEE d ' of ' MMMM yyyy hh:mm:ss a").withLocale(Locale.US);
```